# Bootstrap button to new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap style form with a button. The button's function is to move to a different page only when the inputs in the form are all filled out. Thus, I added "required" in input tags. I also added window.location="url" in the javascript function for the button. However, doing so results in redirecting to new page disregarding the fact the inputs are empty. So, in the javascript function, I added some if statements to check if the strings from inputs have greater than 0 length, and move to new page only when the strings have greater than 0 length. But, then, even when all the inputs are filled out, the page just refreshes and does not move to the new page. Does anyone know how to make this work?

HTML file:

```
<form>
  <input id="email" required>
  <input id="password" required>
  <button onclick="login()">Log in</button>
</form>
```

JS file:

```
function login() {
  var email = $("#email").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();

  if (email.length == 0 || password.length == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  window.location = "index.html";
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what you are doing wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: just added a simplified version of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the form is submitting. Try adding `return false;` to the end of the login function.

Comment: Do you mean after window.location="index.html" ?
I added it and it is still not working.

Comment: Ah, try also changing the button to `<button onclick="return login();">`

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much! Looks like I have to study javascript all over again